# In Xcode, how do I simulate gyroscope for iPhone4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulation, gyroscope

I want to test a web application URL which requires gyroscope.

**I have installed xcode and simulated an iphone4** but if I try to access any gyroscope enabled web application it does not work. I searched and found I have to add some hardware capabilities for it. **Can anyone tell me the process I can follow to simulate a gyroscope enabled iPhone using Xcode?**

**Currently I don't have a iphone with gyroscope and don't want to buy one just for testing.**

I am running: Xcode Version 4.3.1 (4E1019)
and Mac mini with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50d)

Comment: Seeing as though your computer doesn't have gyroscopes, I'm sorry to say that no this can't be simulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check gyroscope functionality in simulator using xcode.. you'll have to test on real device..